# Why am I not able to import my web scraping data in MySQL database? it's showing error

Tags: python, sql, scrapy, mysql-connector-python

```
import mysql.connector

class WatsonPipeline:
    def __init__(self):
        self.con = mysql.connector.connect(
            host='127.0.0.1',
            user= 'root',
            passwd='5779ra',
            database='watson')
        self.cur = self.con.cursor()

        self.cur.execute("""
        create table dahyun_table(
        title text,
        link text,
        price float
        )""")
    def process_item(self,item,spider):
        self.cur.execute("""
        insert into dahyun_table (title,link,price) values (%s,%s,%s)""",(
            item['title'],
            item['link'],
            item['price']
        ))
        self.con.commit()
        self.con.close()
        return item
```

**Output**

> _mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Python type list cannot be converted

I want to put my web scraping data in MySQL. But I'm facing the above error.

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please edit the question and add the whole error traceback message.

Comment: include the entirety of the error message

Comment: that means that either the title the link or the price is a list, which is not an acceptable data type for the mysql api